# How to use the collectRates method in a shipping module to collect table rates

Tags: module, magento-1, shipping, table-rates

I am creating a shipping module that will use table rates for determining the amount to be charged for shipping. My question is, do I use the collectRates method in the shipping module to display the table rates, or what do I do in this scenario?

Any insight, ideas, and/or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You should extend or overwrite tablerate shipping method and you can use tablerate original methods plus you can add own business rules

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`collectRates()` is called for each shipping module.
It receives as parameter an object instance of `Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request`. Let's call it `$request`.
Your `collectRates()` method should start like this:

```
if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
   return false;
}
```

This means 'do nothing if the shipping method is disabled'.
Through the `$request` parameter you have access to all the products in the cart:
`$request->getAllItems()`.
You can get the total weight of the cart like this:

```
$request->getPackageWeight()
```

You can get the total number of products in the cart (qty):

```
$request->getPackageQty()
```

You can get the shipping address details as follows:

```
$request->getDestCountryId(); //for country code
$request->getDestRegionCode(); //for region id (if the country supports it
$request->getDestPostcode();//postal code
$request->getDestCity();//city
$request->getDestStreet();//street
```

These are the most important ones. For the additional info see the methods listed at the top of this class `Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request`.
Based on this info you can calculate a price (or more prices) for delivery.
After you have the prices your `collectRates` method should return an instance of `Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result`.
For this create an instance:

```
$result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
```

Each result can support different methods for different prices. For each method you need to do the following:

```
$method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');//create a method instance
$method->setCarrier('some_code_here'); //set the carrier code (usually the code of your shipping method)
$method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));//set the carrier title (usually rhe name of the shipping method)
$method->setMethod('some_method_code_here'); //a code for the shipping method. Example: 'express', 'fast_delivery'...It can also be the carrier code if you have only one method for the carrier
$method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name')); //the method title 
$method->setPrice(THE CALCULATED SHIPPING PRICE HERE);
$method->setCost(ADDITIONAL COST HERE); //if you don't have an additional cost (for handling for example) skip this line.
$result->append($method); //append the method to the result.
```

After finishing adding your methods simply return the result:

```
return $result;
```

Comment: nice explanation!

Comment: @Marius how to add Error message for any shipping method, please have look at these question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25556/magento-use-custom-error-message-in-shipping-method

Comment: @Marius I am using custom shipping modules ( same like above ) but have one issue on onepage. When i update product qty at checkout page it should be show free shipping ( according to price ) . but shipping methods not showing . If i update 2 time then its showing. its working proper on checkout/cart page .