# Shipping Price Based On Manufacturer Attribute

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I have a unique requirement from client for setting shipping charges from them. The requirement is as follows.

1) They are having products from different parts of the world. 
2) They need to set shipping price based on brands of that product.
3) It is same like Brands Vs Destination table rates.

What they need is this

Here the shipping cost is for 1 product. its something like Brand VS No Of Items Vs Destination.

Can anyone help me in this. Also please let me know if there are any extensions available for it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That one is a complex one, you need dynamic pricing, Magento does not work on that basis.

It is multiple times worse if you ship internationally with multiple checkout currencies. We know exactly what you need, however your description does not fully take in to account the business process. Normally it is COGS calculations, then duties and markup, then discounts, then shipping outbound from the warehouse to the destination, if you are working on a drop-ship basis it is a different calculation. Shipping is normally only one part of the problem, rolling the COGS and markup calculations in to it will cause other issues. We use a solution from enterprise consultants who worked with systems such as SAP, Magento does not have that level of functionality built in to it.

As already suggested you can adapt the shipping calculations however from your description it sounds like issue is the complete supply chain rather than the end point.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to set the price during the checkout process. 
First, check this article : [How to use the collectRates method in a shipping module to collect table rates](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4619/how-to-use-the-collectrates-method-in-a-shipping-module-to-collect-table-rates).

In the collectRates() method check the brand of the product and set the correct price.
You can find more general info about shipping modules here:

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-create-custom-shipping-method

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/15/create-custom-shipping-methods-magento/

In both of these articles, there is a good explanation of the collectRates() method. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Lee safarite(Lokey Coding) has a PerItemShipping module on github. 
https://github.com/LokeyCoding

I would think the perItemShipping module and the ShippingAdjustments module would be a good place to start to piece together a custom solution if you have a lot of variation in the brands etc.

If it's only the two listed above, per product shipping might be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar requirement for one of my project where i need to have different shipping price for different products. [Product Based Shipping](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/item-based-shipping.html) extension helped me a lot. You can have different shipping prices for individual items. You can configure it for manufacture also.
I think it will help you too.