# relation/communication between `getEstimateRates()` & `collectRates()` these methods to collect the shipping & Tax rates?

Tags: magento-1.8, php-5.4

I am new to magento, When url goes to `checkout/cart/index` or `checkout/onepage/index` magento should be showing Shipping Rates. These Shipping Rates are getting from `$this->getEstimateRates()` method from `magento\app\design\frontend\easylife\default\template\shpmethod\cart\shipping.phtml` file. from  `getEstimateRates()` these method or sub methods doesn't have method of `collectRates()`, but it's returning an result of Shipping Rates.

When I Creating Log from `collectRates()` method which is located on `magento\app\code\core\Mage\Usa\Model\Shipping\Carrier\Ups.php` this file log's are creating.

**My Question is:**

1) How the scenario was going on to collect shipping & Tax rates?

2) where is the relation/communication between `getEstimateRates()` & `collectRates()` these methods to collect shipping & Tax rates?

3) Is it possible to save the `xml request & response` when it `collectrates`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1,2) `collectRates()` will ultimately call `getEstimateRates()`.

> collectRates() is called for each shipping module.
>   It receives as parameter an object instance of Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request

3) Saving the Request is possible via [`Varien_Io_File`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Varien/Varien_Io/Varien_Io_File.html) or `Mage::log()`

- [How to use the collectRates method in a shipping module to collect table rates](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4619/how-to-use-the-collectrates-method-in-a-shipping-module-to-collect-table-rates)